# How grab lines which are start with two specific words in R

Tags: regex, r

I am going to grab lines which are starting with student or faculty I use.

```
textdata <- grep("([^student|^faculty])", textdata, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE )
```

but it give me some lines which are start with words such as course too. I really appreciate any help

Comment: Remove the `[` and `]`. You could also probably make it `^(student|faculty)`

Comment: You could also give us  a reproducible example with some sample data.